# Laravel Voyager - two dropdown "Category" and "Subcategory"

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel Voyager admin panel.

I have a 'products' table where PRODUCT has parent SUBCATEGORY and CATEGORY. I have also made these relationships: 'product-subcategory' and 'product-category'.

[image: Screenshot]

So, when I want to add new product, I can choose CATEGORY and SUBCATEGORY from dropdown.

The problem is, SUBCATEGORY dropdown shows all of the subcategories:

I want see the SUBCATEGORIES only from the CATEGORY I choose. (like we get the column names of specified MODEL(for referencing) when we create relationships in voyager)

The reason I want this is to prevent adding products under the wrong Category and Subcategory.

Is there a way to achieve this? Should I use some JSON in the 'Optional Details' field?

Comment: the do an ajax for get subcategory from server when someone select category

Comment: Check out this tutorial here https://appdividend.com/2018/02/07/laravel-ajax-tutorial-example/ on how to setup a AJAX controller and be able to do queries.  Then using some JavaScript libraries you can reload the 'subCategory' drop down choices every time a category is picked.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want is not possible with default Voyager options. but It's not even necessary to do what you want this way.

Following method will make a single dropdown containing options like `category - subcategory`.

1. the good way is to connect sub_categories to categories (using category_id on sub_categories) and then connect products to sub_categories ( using sub_category_id on products).
2. then edit your SubCategory Model and change title value using Laravel [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```php
class Product{
   //stuff

   //change showing attribute value for BREAD
   public function getTitleAttribute(){
      return $this->category->title . ' - ' . $this->getOriginal('title');
   }

   // access original subcategory title
   public function getRealTitleAttirbute(){
      return $this->getOriginal('title');
   }
}
```

its done. just notice we can access subcategory's real value using `$subcategory->real_title`.

good luck